# How to retry api calls using node-fetch

Tags: node.js, node-fetch

I am trying to POST a request to external API using node-fetch in my node js code.
I want to retry the request 3 times if there are any timeouts or network failures while doing the POST request.
Could you let me know how to retry the request using node-fetch? I see that there is a npm module https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch-retry but it doesnt seem to work as expected and it also doesn't accept retry interval between retries. Any code snippets will be very helpful.

EDIT:

Thanks i tried using promise-fn-retry but it doesnt seem to do any retry. Below is the code snippet i tried by switching off my WIFI and then doing the FETCH call to see if it retried 3 times. But it does the fetch just once and returns the error.

```
const promiseFn = () => fetch(url,{method:"POST",headers:header,body:JSON.stringify(payload)});
const options = {
  times: 3,
  initialDelay: 100,
  onRetry: (error) => {
    console.log(error);
      }
};
console.log('PromiseFn result ****'+retry(promiseFn, options).then(res => res.json()).then((res)=>{console.log('Promise Fn result is'+JSON.stringify(res))}).catch((err)=>{console.log('Error in Promise Fn'+err)}));
```

Answer (score 15):

this snippet helped me in the past! Hope it is what you are looking for

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const delay = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms));

const retryFetch = (
  url,
  fetchOptions = {},
  retries = 3,
  retryDelay = 1000,
  timeout
) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // check for timeout
    if (timeout) setTimeout(() => reject('error: timeout'), timeout);

    const wrapper = (n) => {
      fetch(url, fetchOptions)
        .then((res) => resolve(res))
        .catch(async (err) => {
          if (n > 0) {
            await delay(retryDelay);
            wrapper(--n);
          } else {
            reject(err);
          }
        });
    };

    wrapper(retries);
  });
};

retryFetch('http://localhost:8080/test', {}, 20)
  .then((res) => res.text())
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: This works fine but is there any way we can specify a timeout?

Comment: Hi, this is a 'quick and dirty 'solution for timeout. If answer suits you, mark it as accepted. hope to have been helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the [promise-fn-retry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-fn-retry) package, it has properties to specify retry times, initial delay time and callback methods to handle failed fetch/promises.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks i tried using promise-fn-retry but it doesnt seem to do any retry.I have edited the question to add code snippets i used for promise-fn-retry.