# How to access a function that is in useEffect on component level without duplicating the function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So I have a React component that fetches books from an API on first render, but then if the request fails for some reason, I want to retry the function again, but the scope of the function is inside of useEffect only, do I need to make another duplicate function on app level or is there a way around this?

```
// I want to access `fetchBooks` function up here

  useEffect(() => {
    const controller = new AbortController();

// This function loads books from the backend
    const fetchBooks = async () => {
      try {
        setLoad({ type: "page", ongoing: true });
        const response = await axios({
          method: "GET",
          url: "https://myURL/api/v1/products/books",
          signal: controller.signal,
        });

        setBooks(response.data.result);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    };
    fetchBooks();

// Cleanup to abort the function
    return () => {
      controller.abort();
      console.log("component unmounts");
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: You may want to consider abstracting out the code that performs the request to a separate function that handles its own retry logic, and does not resolve the promise/return a response until all of the retries have happened. The retry logic generally be catching a failure and recursively calling the API function again. This question may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59854115/how-to-retry-api-calls-using-node-fetch

Answer (score 1):

Move the `fetchBooks` to the body of the component (or custom hook), and wrap it with `useCallback`. You'll need to move the `AbortController`, so it would be available to the function, and the `useEffect` cleanup function:

```
const controller = useRef();

const fetchBooks = useCallback(async () => {
  controller.current = new AbortController();
  
  try {
    setLoad({
      type: "page",
      ongoing: true
    });
    const response = await axios({
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://myURL/api/v1/products/books",
      signal: controller.current.signal,
    });

    setBooks(response.data.result);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  fetchBooks();

  // Cleanup to abort the function
  return () => {
    controller.current ? .abort();
    console.log("component unmounts");
  };
}, [fetchBooks]);
```

Comment: This answer does not demonstrate how to retry the fetch on failure.

Comment: Read the question again. How to make to the retry is not part of the scope of the question.

Comment: "then if the request fails for some reason, I want to **retry** the function again"

Comment: "How to access a function that is in useEffect on component level without duplicating the function?". The question is about "not duplicating". Feel free to ask the OP for clarifications.

Comment: The function itself does one thing which is fetching books, and it's such that whether its called in useEffect or triggered by a button, it will work.